# The Matter Anti Matter Asymmetry

Tags: cosmology, universe, matter, antimatter

The matter anti matter asymmetry is still a mystery that still can't be explained. But what if there wasn't an asymmetry? Isn't it possible that there was exactly equal amounts of matter and anti matter which did in fact annihilate each other, and the energy released from it was converted into mass? I know this arises a lot of paradoxes like if so what kind of matter is everything then . I guess what I really want to know more about is, after a Matter and Anti Matter collision, what kind of matter can be created (or rather converted) from the resulting energy outburst?

Comment: Related question on the Physics Stack Exchange: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263729/why-do-we-believe-baryon-asymmetry

Answer (score 3):

Energy can indeed transform into matter - for example [pair production](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production); but this creates equal amounts of matter and anti-matter.

Answer (score 1):

Many products are created by Matter and Anti Matter collision but is dependent on what matter antimatter that is annihilating. Example electron and a positron annihilate create 2 photons. Proton-anti-proton annihilation produces as many as nine mesons have been observed. If there were equal amounts of matter and antimatter in the beginning we would now see high amounts of gamma rays at the boundary's between regions of matter and antimatter. Which we do not observe. That is my answer.

Comment: You are right uhoh. I over simplified. Thank you for the constructive criticism.  

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4186.pdf
THE MATTER-ANTIMATTER ASYMMETRY OF THE UNIVERSE
https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0207323.pdf
Quark Annihilation and Lepton Formation versus Pair Production and Neutrino
Oscillation: The Fourth Generation of Leptons
http://www.ptep-online.com/2011/PP-25-05.PDF
Antineutrino-neutrino and antineutrino-electron
https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0206273.pdf
Antiproton–proton annihilation into pion pairs within effective
meson theory
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.05520.pdf

Comment: The formation of antimatter happened around 10^-34 sec's right after cosmic inflation. Then at around 10^-10 sec's anti-quarks disappeared. Then the disappearance of positrons happen around 10^2 sec's. Then the formation of matter around 10^13 sec's after the Big Bang. 

https://books.google.com/books?id=c3-p7lHUcwoC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=CERN+(photo-di/9108002))&source=bl&ots=1SrppO33PG&sig=ACfU3U3XrMFPw1meT2pQY8952s6XCpqlnA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqiKbepu7nAhU-l3IEHQGBCm4Q6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=CERN%20(photo-di%2F9108002))&f=false

Comment: My final answer! @uhoh

Comment: Looks much better, *thank you very much!*